# Which are the ANSI C language extensions disabled by the /Za option in Visual Studio?

Tags: c, visual-studio, gcc

I work in a cross-platform environment where many tools (written in C) are compiled by both Visual Studio on Windows and GCC on Linux, as some co-workers prefer to debug with Visual Studio and some with Eclipse/GDB, etc. on Linux.

When we recently relaxed the warning levels for these internal tools for GCC, reverting basically to the "default" warnings + `-O3` we got a mismatch in error-level compared to Visual Studio.

Is there a way to get the specific language extensions disabled by the `/Za` switch in Visual Studio, so that we can align the compilation errors? It would be nice to be able to check-in after testing compilation with GCC without compile-break in Visual Studio.

So far I know that Visual Studio by default allows C++ style comments. What else?

Comment: GCC also allows C++ style comments.

Comment: @Bo: Thanks - for some reason I had just searched for this within stackoverflow :-) If you paste your link as an answer I will accept it. @Dhaivat - yes I know, but I was looking for the differences and it is somewhat easier enabling/disabling specific extensions in gcc with the `Werror=` switch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find the [Microsoft Extensions to C and C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34h23df8.aspx) page at MSDN.